# Cannot assign an array to another

Tags: c

I tried through different ways to copy an array pointer to another one, without any success.
Here are my attempts, with the associated error message.

```
typedef long int coordinate;
typedef coordinate coordinates[3];

void test(coordinates coord) {
    coordinates coord2 = coord; // error: invalid initializer
    coordinates coord3;
    coord3 = coord; // error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘coordinates’ from type ‘long int *’
    coord3 = (coordinates) coord; // error: cast specifies array type
    coord3 = (coordinate[]) coord; // error: cast specifies array type
    coord3 = (long int*) coord; // error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘coordinates’ from type ‘long int *’
}
```

I know I could use `typedef coordinate* coordinates;` instead, but it does not look very explicit to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot assign arrays in C. Use `memcpy` to copy an array into another.

```
coordinates coord2;

memcpy(coord2, coord, sizeof coord2);
```

Comment: At first, I was looking for a way to keep the same data, but only copy the pointer. However, it now looks clearly better to copy data.
Thank you for the tip and the code.

Comment: @valentinLorentz of course if you don't *need* to copy the data, working with pointers would be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

When arrays are passed by value, they [*decay to pointers*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1461449/335858). The common trick to work around that is wrapping your fixed-size array in a `struct`, like this:

```
struct X {
    int val[5];
};

struct X a = {{1,2,3,4,5}};
struct X b;
b = a;
for(i=0;i!=5;i++)
    printf("%d\n",b.val[i]);
```

Now you can pass your wrapped arrays by value to functions, assign them, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your coordinates need to be initialized as pointers

`coordinates *coords2, *coords3;`

Try that out and then assign.

Comment: But that won't actually copy the data.

Comment: true, it would be a pointer assigned to the same array
@ouah has the better answer on this one

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign one array to another using the assignment operator, e.g. `a = b`, because an array doesn't know the size of itself.

This is the reason why we cannot assign one array to another using the assignment operator.